# Excluding records per calculation

Tags: tableau-api

I am attempting to use Tableau to filter through some data, but I can't get the Tableau calculation right. I am trying to exclude employees where
max = 1 and role = Supervisor or Manager. So, in theory, the only record that should show would be the Analyst record. I have a calculation I am using as a filter, but it of course doesn't work as desired. I'm relatively new to Tableau, so if there is a better way, I am open to it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Data set

```
| EMPLOYEE |       ROLE |      STATUS |            STARTDATE | MAX |
|----------|------------|-------------|----------------------|-----|
|    12311 | Supervisor |  Active     | 2016-07-12T00:00:00Z |   1 |
|    12311 | Analyst    |  Not Active | 2015-06-11T00:00:00Z |   0 |
|    12311 | Help Desk  |  Not Active | 2014-05-12T00:00:00Z |   0 |
|    23432 | Manager    |  Active     | 2012-11-02T00:00:00Z |   1 |
|    23432 | Associate  |  Not Active | 2011-04-23T00:00:00Z |   0 |
|    54332 | Analyst    |  Resigned   | 2015-10-15T00:00:00Z |   1 |
```

What I have so far:

```
IF [MAX] = 1 AND [ROLE] = "MANAGER" OR [ROLE] = "SUPERVISOR"
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are case Sensitive, so you have to use the exact same string in your calculation.If you have a leading space in the data, you have to add it as well or trim the field.It is also better to add brackets to prevent ambiguity.

[image]
[image]